# How to modify arrows in bootstrap accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, accordion

I wrote some JavaScript and tried to replace the class whenever the aria-expanded element is true or false but nothing seems to be happening
The first card is open when the page loads because the aria-expanded ="true".
I want to find a way to replace the class in  whenever the value of the aria-expanded element is changed. I'm new to jQuery and webdev so all of your help is appreciated.
Edit-I used bootstrap accordion to make sure only one can be open at a time

```html
<div id="headingOne">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        Or Files
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" href="#collapseFiles" 
          role="button" aria-expanded="true" data-target="#collapseFiles" 
          aria-controls="collapseNotes">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-up></i>
        </a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div id="headingTwo">
             <h5 class="card-title">
             Or Notes
                <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" href="#collapseNotes" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapseNotes" aria-controls="collapseNotes">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
              </h5>
  </div>
<div id="headingThree">
             <h5 class="card-title">
             Or Names
                <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" href="#collapseNames" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapseNames" aria-controls="collapseNotes">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
              </h5>
  </div>
```

and this is the jquery.

```js
if ($('a').attr('aria-expanded').val() == 'true') {
    $("a i").attr("class", "fa-angle-down");
} else {
    $("a i").attr("class", "fa-angle-up");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you might want to do it using JavaScript, but I have a pure CSS way to do it:

#### HTML

I removed all unnecessary attributes on the anchor tag. I also removed `fa-angle-down` on the icon. The icon state will be set via CSS.

```html
<div id="headingOne">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        Or Files
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" data-target="#collapseFiles">
            <i class="fas"></i>
        </a>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p id="collapseFiles" class="card-text collapse show">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of 
            the card's content.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="headingTwo">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        Or Notes
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" data-target="#collapseNotes">
            <i class="fas"></i>
        </a>
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p id="collapseNotes" class="card-text collapse show">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of 
            the card's content.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="headingThree">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        Or Name
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" data-target="#collapseNames">
            <i class="fas"></i>
        </a>
    </h5>
    <div  class="card-body">
        <p id="collapseNames" class="card-text collapse show">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of 
            the card's content.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

You can write CSS to target any anchor tag that has `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute. When it collapses, Bootstraps adds `.collapsed` class so that you can use it to style the icon accordingly.

```css
a[data-toggle="collapse"] i.fas:before {
    content: "\f107";    /* angle-down */
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed i.fas:before {
    content: "\f106";    /* angle-up */
}
```

#### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

#### Fiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/og1t8ksj/26/

Comment: this seems to only work for only one card element. it's my mistake though, I didn't include multiple in my question. I have made edits to the question if you had any suggestions.

Comment: @TerriSong: they're all controlling the same `#collapseNotes`?

Comment: sorry about that. Made a mistake while copying

Comment: @TerriSong: It still works. Please check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use events to catch a change, for example
https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-up').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
    } else {
        $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="headingTwo">
    <h5 class="card-title">
        Or Notes
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" href="#collapseNotes" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#collapseNotes" aria-controls="collapseNotes">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
        </a>
    </h5>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseNotes">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be making any changes as well

Comment: I have added the snippet and now you can see the output.

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while, but I think this is probably a good answer to this question:
NO NEED TO USE JAVASCRIPT for this. Take advantage of the class 'collapsed' which is added to the wrapping 'a' when the accordion is collapsed.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" class="float-right" href="#collapseFiles" 
      role="button" aria-expanded="true" data-target="#collapseFiles" 
      aria-controls="collapseNotes">
  <span class="arrowup"> <i class="fas fa-angle-up></i> </span>
  <span class="arrowdown"> <i class="fas fa-angle-dowm></i> </span>
</a>
```

then on your stylesheet:

.accordion .arrowdown {
       display: none
     } 
----------
     .accordion .collapsed .arrowup {
       display: none
     }
---------
     .accordion .collapsed .arrowdown{
       display: block
     }

Comment: This is the same implementation of the approved answer on an old question